git config: more insteadOf on the same url elide each other
I'd like to have a ~/.gitconfig containing redirections of different URLs (here for sake of simplicity "aaa" and "bbb") onto the same one (again for simplicity "1234")
I can do this if I write the file manually, but I've noticed that if instead I set it via git config the 2nd setting is going to elide the previous one:
╭─ 
╰─ mv ~/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig.backup && : > ~/.gitconfig && cat ~/.gitconfig

╭─ 
╰─ git config --global url."1234".insteadOf "aaa" && cat ~/.gitconfig
[url "1234"]
        insteadOf = aaa

╭─ 
╰─ git config --global url."1234".insteadOf "bbb" && cat ~/.gitconfig
[url "1234"]
        insteadOf = bbb

I would have expected to have a ~/.gitconfig containing this (like I was able to do manually):
[url "1234"]
        insteadOf = aaa
[url "1234"]
        insteadOf = bbb

I'm on last git version:
╭─ 
╰─ git -v
git version 2.45.0


See the --add option to git config meant to add multiple lines without altering previous values i.e. git config --global url."1234".insteadOf "aaa" && git config --global --add url."1234".insteadOf "bbb" && cat ~/.gitconfig

Thank you very much @Zeitounator. That did exactly the trick!

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-config%5D+multiple+%22insteadOf%22
